# try catch block in redux toolkit async thunk, avoide duplicate code

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So I have async thunk functions in features folder on top of slice file, in `Redux - toolkit`, and they all share same try catch code that I would like to move to separate try-catch function.(code is working). `getPostComments` and exectra are axios requests.

```
export const fetchComments = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchComments', async (id: number, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    return await getPostComments(id);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.message);
    }

    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('something went wrong');
  }
});

export const addComment = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/addComment', async (data: CommentData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await createComment(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.message);
      }

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('something went wrong');
    }
  },
);

export const removeComment = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/removeComment', async (id: number, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      await deleteComment(id);

      return id;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.message);
      }

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('something went wrong');
    }
  },
);
```

So for first thunk I tried to make separate try-catch callback function, but I already recieve typescript errors like : `TS2304: Cannot find name 'GetThunkAPI'`. And I want to make this callback generic at least for this file thunks.

```
const tryCatchMiddleware = async (
  callback: (arg: number) => Promise<Comment[]>,
  thunkAPI: GetThunkAPI<{}>,
  arg: number,
) => {
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/return-await
    return await callback(arg);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.message);
    }

    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('something went wrong');
  }
};

// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
export const fetchComments = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchComments', async (id: number, thunkAPI) => {
  tryCatchMiddleware(getPostComments, thunkAPI, id);
});
```

error: [image]

error: [image]

May be you can suggest some best practices or give usefull links. I heard that this hustle can be avoided by using RTK-Query, or Saga, but how to fix this without them.
Also here is packages.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/react": "^5.12.4",
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.4",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "cypress": "^9.5.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
```